# BTS7960 pwm values

Tags: java, pi4j, kotlin

I have a [BTS7960 h-bridge](https://www.ebay.com/p/BTS-7960-43-a-H-Bridge-High-Power-Intelligent-Vehicle-Motor-Driver-Module/1133093528) and I am trying to make a motor to move forward and backward using pwm values. I am using the `pi4j` library to control the pins.

The pins `L_EN` and `R_EN` are initialized as `DigitalOutputPin`s.

**Case Study 1**

When I am initializing all the `R_PWM` and `L_PWM` as `DigitalOutputPin`s the motor can move forward and backward at full speed.

**Case Study 2**

When I am trying to initialize the `R_PWM` and `L_PWM` pins as `PwmOutputPin`s the motor cannot move.

**Case Study 3**

When I am trying to initialize the `R_PWM` as `DigitalOutputPin` and `L_PWM` as `PwmOutputPin` the motor moves to one direction only.

It seems that this h-bridge does not work when pin is set to 0 using pwm but it works when pin is set to 0 in digital!

I wonder why this is happening.

If you need to check my source code please see [here](https://github.com/BILLyTheLiTTle/RaspiTests/blob/master/src/BTS7960MotorDriver.kt)

Comment: I do not understand the problem.  You should only be applying PWM to one pin at any one time.  The other pin should be set low.

Comment: When the other pin is set to low (using DigitalOutputPin) everything is working like a charm but when is set to 0 (using PwmOutputPin) it is not working. I have found a workaround but I am wondering is there any difference between pwm low and digital low values?

Comment: There should be no difference between PWM with duty cycle 0 and setting the pin low.  Perhaps this is an unintended feature of the Pi4J implementation.  Raise an issue?

Comment: I was reading in a forum that in Arduino it has the same functionality! Please see here (http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=148482.0) the answer by dc42. The answer #5 in the sequence, bullet no2.